# How to exclude particular rows from dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I'm following "Intro to Statistical Learning" but doing everything in python instead of R. I am trying to take my dataframe and exclude certain rows from it, and then summarize those rows to get new values. My code does not seem to be doing that and I was wondering where the issue could be?

When I use the .describe function the second time, I am getting the exact same values with no changes. I was wondering what the issue is.

Here is the code:

````
autoData = pd.read_csv('Auto.csv')

print(autoData.describe()) # Gives all the information. The range, std, mean etc

auto2 = autoData.drop(autoData.iloc[:10, 85:])
print(auto2.describe())```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of dropping those rows, slice on the ones you want to keep:

```
auto2 = autoData.iloc[10:,:85]
```

Comment: Lol... well that was an easy fix. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this in case need to select specific columns

```
df7=df3.iloc[10:13,[2,3,4,5,8]]
```

or by columns names and row number;

```
df7=df3.loc[10:,['AFYP','POLICY_ID']]
```

Hope it helps